# Output not displaying full list of elements appended

Tags: python, append

```
from csv import reader

def func(sku_list):
    values = []
    with open(sku_list, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as pr:
        rows = reader(pr)
        for sku in rows:
            values.append(sku[1])
    return(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dir_path = "C:/Users/XXXX/Downloads/"
    vendors = dir_path + 'file.csv'
    new_prices = func(vendors)
    print(new_prices)
```

`sku_list` is a csv file filled with pairs of brand names and their skus that I have downloaded from my db, for some reason as it iters through the rows and grabs just the sku value, hence `sku[1]`, it stops well short of the actual length I expect the list to be

`sku_list` is 85,892 tuples long but when I print out the values appended to the list `values` it simply returns this:

```
['SKU', 'MWGB4896', 'MWGB4872', 'MWGB4848', 'MWGB3648', 'WGB4896', 'WGB4872', 'WGB4848', 'WGB3648', 'WGB2436', 'WGB1824', 'BKGB4896NT', 'BKGB4872NT', 'BKGB4848NT', 'BKGB3648NT', 'BKGB2436NT', 'BKGB1824NT', 'WFC2418G', 'WFC2418', 'WFC3624', 'WFC2418LB', 'WFC3648LB', 'WFC3624LB', 'WFC3624G', 'WFC3648G', 'WFC3648', 'LOWFC3624LB', 'LOWFC3624G', 'LOWFC3624', 'LOWFC2418LB', 'LOWFC2418G', 'LOWFC2418', 'LOWFC3648LB', 'LOWFC3648', 'LOWFC3648G', 'WM-7-B', 'WM-7-G', 'WM-7-BK', 'WMC-7', 'WM-7-R', 'APS-50', 'APS-70', 'APS-60', 'APS-84', 'SS15W', 'SC15W', 'SB15W', 'MFL-2W', 'WP-48', 'WP-40', 'WP-36', 'MP-48', 'MP-40', 'MP-36', 'OP-40', 'OP-36', 'OP-48', 'FFVSU96-2', 'FFVSU144-2', 'FFVSU192-2', '1-WA-1B', '1-WA-1BP', 'WCS-12', 'WCS-144', 'OPLD3416LSPP-2', 'OPLD3416LSPP-4', 'OPLD3416LSPP-5', 'OPLD3416LSPP-7', 'OPLD3416LSPP-8', 'OPLD1818LSPP-2', 'OPLD1818LSPP-4', 'OPLD1818LSPP-5', 'OPLD1818LSPP-7', 'OPLD1818LSPP-8', 'OPLD1818L-2', 'OPLD1818L-5', 'OPLD1818L-4', 'OPLD3416L-2', 'OPLD3416L-4', 'OPLD3416L-5', 'OPLD3416L-7', 'OPLD3416L-8', 'OPLD1818L-7', 'OPLD1818L-8', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-892', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-897', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-878', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-885', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-887', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-890', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-845', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-854', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-856', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-876', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-802', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-706', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-705', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-704', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-837', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-831', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-819', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-812', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-685', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-683', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-679', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-531', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-703', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-702', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-701', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-700', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-892', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-897', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-887', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-890', 'OPLD3416SPP-8-530', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-845', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-854', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-831', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-837', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-878', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-885', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-856', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-876', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-703', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-702', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-705', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-704', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-802', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-706', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-819', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-812', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-530', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-679', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-531', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-685', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-683', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-701', 'OPLD3416SPP-7-700', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-878', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-885', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-887', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-890', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-892', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-897', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-812', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-819', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-831', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-837', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-845', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-854', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-856', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-876', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-819', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-831', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-802', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-812', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-854', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-856', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-837', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-845', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-701', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-702', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-685', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-700', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-705', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-706', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-703', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-704', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-887', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-885', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-878', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-876', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-897', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-892', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-890', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-837', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-831', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-854', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-845', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-802', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-706', 
'OPLD3416SPP-4-819', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-812', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-890', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-887', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-897', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-892', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-876', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-856', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-885', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-878', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-531', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-679', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-683', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-685', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-530', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-704', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-705', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-706', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-802', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-700', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-701', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-702', 'OPLD3416SPP-5-703', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-837', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-831', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-819', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-812', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-802', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-706', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-705', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-704', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-890', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-887', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-885', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-878', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-876', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-856', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-854', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-845', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-531', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-679', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-530', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-892', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-897', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-704', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-705', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-702', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-703', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-700', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-701', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-683', 'OPLD3416SPP-4-685', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-530', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-531', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-679', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-683', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-685', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-700', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-701', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-702', 'OPLD3416SPP-2-703', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-819', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-831', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-837', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-845', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-705', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-706', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-802', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-812', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-701', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-702', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-703', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-704', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-679', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-683', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-685', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-700', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-531', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-530', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-683', 'OPLD1818SPP-8-679', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-897', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-887', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-885', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-892', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-890', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-856', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-854', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-878', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-876', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-819', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-831', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-802', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-812', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-705', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-706', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-703', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-704', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-701', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-702', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-685', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-700', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-679', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-683', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-530', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-531', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-531', 'OPLD1818SPP-7-530', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-897', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-892', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-890', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-887', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-885', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-878', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-876', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-856', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-854', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-845', 'OPLD1818SPP-5-837', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-701', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-702', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-703', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-704', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-705', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-706', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-802', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-812', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-530', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-531', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-679', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-683', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-685', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-700', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-887', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-837', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-845', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-854', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-856', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-802', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-812', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-819', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-831', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-890', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-892', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-897', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-876', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-878', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-885', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-887', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-531', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-530', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-683', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-679', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-704', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-703', 
'OPLD1818SPP-2-706', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-705', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-700', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-685', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-702', 'OPLD1818SPP-2-701', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-876', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-878', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-854', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-856', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-837', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-845', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-819', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-831', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-897', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-890', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-892', 'OPLD1818SPP-4-885', 'PLD4832DPP-2-845', 'PLD4832DPP-2-837', 'PLD4832DPP-2-856', 'PLD4832DPP-2-854', 'PLD4832DPP-2-878', 'PLD4832DPP-2-876', 'PLD4832DPP-2-887', 'PLD4832DPP-2-885', 'PLD4832DPP-2-892', 'PLD4832DPP-2-890', 'PLD4832DPP-2-897', 'PLD4832DPP-4-531', 'PLD4832DPP-4-530', 'PLD4832DPP-4-679', 'PLD4832DPP-4-683', 'PLD4832DPP-4-685', 'PLD4832DPP-4-700', 'PLD4832DPP-4-701', 'PLD4832DPP-4-702', 'PLD4832DPP-4-703', 'PLD4832DPP-4-704', 'PLD4832DPP-4-705', 'PLD4832DPP-4-706', 'PLD4832DPP-4-802', 'PLD4832DPP-4-812', 'PLD4832DPP-4-819', 'PLD4832DPP-4-831', 'PLD4832DPP-4-837', 'PLD4832DPP-4-845', 'PLD4832DPP-4-878', 'PLD4832DPP-4-876', 'PLD4832DPP-4-856', 'PLD4832DPP-4-854', 'PLD4832DPP-4-892', 'PLD4832DPP-4-890', 'PLD4832DPP-4-887', 'PLD4832DPP-4-885', 'PLD4832DPP-4-897', 'PLD4832DPP-5-683', 'PLD4832DPP-5-679', 'PLD4832DPP-5-531', 'PLD4832DPP-5-530', 'PLD4832DPP-5-701', 'PLD4832DPP-5-702', 'PLD4832DPP-5-685', 'PLD4832DPP-5-700', 'PLD4832DPP-5-705', 'PLD4832DPP-5-706', 'PLD4832DPP-5-703', 'PLD4832DPP-5-704', 'PLD4832DPP-5-819', 'PLD4832DPP-5-831', 'PLD4832DPP-5-802', 'PLD4832DPP-5-812', 'PLD4832DPP-5-854', 'PLD4832DPP-5-856', 'PLD4832DPP-5-837', 'PLD4832DPP-5-845', 'PLD4832DPP-2-701', 'PLD4832DPP-2-702', 'PLD4832DPP-2-685', 'PLD4832DPP-2-700', 'PLD4832DPP-2-679', 'PLD4832DPP-2-683', 'PLD4832DPP-2-530', 'PLD4832DPP-2-531', 'PLD4832DPP-2-819', 'PLD4832DPP-2-831', 'PLD4832DPP-2-802', 'PLD4832DPP-2-812', 'PLD4832DPP-2-705', 'PLD4832DPP-2-706', 'PLD4832DPP-2-703', 'PLD4832DPP-2-704', 'PLD4226DPP-8-887', 'PLD4226DPP-8-890', 'PLD4226DPP-8-892', 'PLD4226DPP-8-897', 'PLD4226DPP-8-856', 'PLD4226DPP-8-876', 'PLD4226DPP-8-878', 'PLD4226DPP-8-885', 'PLD4226DPP-8-831', 'PLD4226DPP-8-837', 'PLD4226DPP-8-845', 'PLD4226DPP-8-854', 'PLD4226DPP-8-706', 'PLD4226DPP-8-802', 'PLD4226DPP-8-812', 'PLD4226DPP-8-819', 'PLD4226DPP-5-892', 'PLD4226DPP-5-897', 'PLD4226DPP-5-887', 'PLD4226DPP-5-890', 'PLD4226DPP-7-530', 'PLD4226DPP-7-683', 'PLD4226DPP-7-685', 'PLD4226DPP-7-531', 'PLD4226DPP-7-679', 'PLD4226DPP-7-702', 'PLD4226DPP-7-703', 'PLD4226DPP-7-700', 'PLD4226DPP-7-701', 'PLD4226DPP-5-705', 'PLD4226DPP-5-704', 'PLD4226DPP-5-703', 'PLD4226DPP-5-702', 'PLD4226DPP-5-819', 'PLD4226DPP-5-812', 'PLD4226DPP-5-802', 'PLD4226DPP-5-706', 'PLD4226DPP-5-854', 'PLD4226DPP-5-845', 'PLD4226DPP-5-837', 'PLD4226DPP-5-831', 'PLD4226DPP-5-885', 'PLD4226DPP-5-878', 'PLD4226DPP-5-876', 'PLD4226DPP-5-856', 'PLD4226DPP-7-892', 'PLD4226DPP-7-897', 'PLD4226DPP-8-530', 'PLD4226DPP-8-531', 'PLD4226DPP-8-679', 'PLD4226DPP-8-683', 'PLD4226DPP-8-685', 'PLD4226DPP-8-700', 'PLD4226DPP-8-701', 'PLD4226DPP-8-702', 'PLD4226DPP-8-703', 'PLD4226DPP-8-704', 'PLD4226DPP-8-705', 'PLD4226DPP-7-705', 'PLD4226DPP-7-704', 'PLD4226DPP-7-802', 'PLD4226DPP-7-706', 'PLD4226DPP-7-819', 'PLD4226DPP-7-812', 'PLD4226DPP-7-837', 'PLD4226DPP-7-831', 'PLD4226DPP-7-854', 'PLD4226DPP-7-845', 'PLD4226DPP-7-876', 'PLD4226DPP-7-856', 'PLD4226DPP-7-885', 'PLD4226DPP-7-878', 'PLD4226DPP-7-890', 'PLD4226DPP-7-887', 'PLD4226DPP-2-892', 'PLD4226DPP-2-897', 'PLD4226DPP-2-887', 'PLD4226DPP-2-890', 'PLD4226DPP-2-878', 'PLD4226DPP-2-885', 'PLD4226DPP-2-856', 'PLD4226DPP-2-876', 'PLD4226DPP-4-683', 'PLD4226DPP-4-685', 'PLD4226DPP-4-531', 'PLD4226DPP-4-679', 'PLD4226DPP-4-530', 'PLD4226DPP-2-705', 'PLD4226DPP-2-704', 'PLD4226DPP-2-703', 'PLD4226DPP-2-702', 'PLD4226DPP-2-701', 'PLD4226DPP-2-700', 'PLD4226DPP-2-685', 'PLD4226DPP-2-683', 'PLD4226DPP-2-854', 'PLD4226DPP-2-845', 'PLD4226DPP-2-837', 'PLD4226DPP-2-831', 'PLD4226DPP-2-819', 'PLD4226DPP-2-812', 'PLD4226DPP-2-802', 'PLD4226DPP-2-706', 'PLD4226DPP-4-892', 'PLD4226DPP-4-897', 'PLD4226DPP-4-878', 'PLD4226DPP-4-885', 'PLD4226DPP-4-887', 'PLD4226DPP-4-890', 'PLD4226DPP-5-683', 'PLD4226DPP-5-685', 'PLD4226DPP-5-700', 'PLD4226DPP-5-701', 'PLD4226DPP-5-530', 'PLD4226DPP-5-531', 'PLD4226DPP-5-679', 'PLD4226DPP-4-705', 'PLD4226DPP-4-704', 'PLD4226DPP-4-802', 'PLD4226DPP-4-706', 'PLD4226DPP-4-701', 'PLD4226DPP-4-700', 'PLD4226DPP-4-703', 'PLD4226DPP-4-702', 'PLD4226DPP-4-854', 'PLD4226DPP-4-845', 'PLD4226DPP-4-876', 'PLD4226DPP-4-856', 'PLD4226DPP-4-819', 'PLD4226DPP-4-812', 'PLD4226DPP-4-837', 'PLD4226DPP-4-831', 'PLD4226DPP-2-530', 'PLD4226DPP-2-679', 'PLD4226DPP-2-531', 'PLD5438DPP-5-683', 'PLD5438DPP-5-685', 'PLD5438DPP-5-531', 'PLD5438DPP-5-679', 'PLD5438DPP-5-702', 'PLD5438DPP-5-703', 'PLD5438DPP-5-700', 'PLD5438DPP-5-701', 'PLD5438DPP-5-706', 'PLD5438DPP-5-802', 'PLD5438DPP-5-704', 'PLD5438DPP-5-705', 'PLD5438DPP-5-831', 'PLD5438DPP-5-837', 'PLD5438DPP-5-812', 'PLD5438DPP-5-819', 'PLD5438DPP-5-876', 'PLD5438DPP-5-856', 'PLD5438DPP-5-854', 'PLD5438DPP-5-845', 'PLD5438DPP-5-890', 'PLD5438DPP-5-887', 'PLD5438DPP-5-885', 'PLD5438DPP-5-878', 'PLD5438DPP-5-897', 'PLD5438DPP-5-892', 'PLD5438DPP-7-679', 'PLD5438DPP-7-531', 'PLD5438DPP-7-530', 'PLD5438DPP-4-530', 'PLD5438DPP-4-531', 'PLD5438DPP-4-679', 'PLD5438DPP-4-683', 'PLD5438DPP-4-685', 'PLD5438DPP-4-700', 'PLD5438DPP-4-701', 'PLD5438DPP-4-702', 'PLD5438DPP-4-703', 'PLD5438DPP-4-704', 'PLD5438DPP-4-705', 'PLD5438DPP-4-706', 'PLD5438DPP-4-802', 'PLD5438DPP-4-812', 'PLD5438DPP-4-819', 'PLD5438DPP-4-837', 'PLD5438DPP-4-831', 'PLD5438DPP-4-854', 'PLD5438DPP-4-845', 'PLD5438DPP-4-876', 'PLD5438DPP-4-856', 'PLD5438DPP-4-885', 'PLD5438DPP-4-878', 'PLD5438DPP-4-890', 'PLD5438DPP-4-887', 'PLD5438DPP-4-897', 'PLD5438DPP-4-892', 'PLD5438DPP-5-530',
'PLD5438DPP
None
```

the final sku in there `PLD5438DPP` should be `PLD5438DPP-5-683` and for some reason the list cuts off there, which is only element 564/85,892, and the program terminates without an error code

I cannot attach the file of skus, this is for my job, just hoping someone can shed light on what I am doing to cause the list to cut short like that

this may or may not also be relevant but when I call `.append(sku)` as opposed to `sku[1]` and grab the whole tuple the same issue occurs but at element 292, exactly half of the amount of element appended when only doing half the tuple

Comment: I am assuming that `reader(pr)` is using the `reader` from the `csv` module. In this case, [according to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), "if _csvfile_ is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`." Does adding `newline=''` to the call to the `open` function work?

Comment: @luuk no, it does not, thank you though, if you have any other ideas let me know

Comment: There could be something going on during the printing of the very long list, what is `len(values)`?

Comment: huh, @luuk interesting, the list is the full size I expected, 85,892 and the last element is containing the correct element, thank you, and sorry for what I now see was just a silly misunderstanding

Comment: @luuk is it typical of python to have errors when printing lists of over 600 elements? and why does it do worse when it is of size > 300 tuples?

Comment: Good to know this was the issue! A small remark; you should usse `return values` instead of `print(values)` in your function if you want to reuse the SKUs in `new_prices` (this is actually the reason why your script also returned `None` on the last line; because `func` didn't return anything, `new_prices` was set to `None`). I haven't encountered any issues with printing long lists myself, this might be something with your terminal or environment in which you run the script and not with Python itself.

Comment: @luuk yes I also noticed that and I've been updating the code I've been running locally, I will also edit it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be one on my local machine, where it was unable to print such a long list, this one was of size 85,892

for those with similar issues see if any of our specs are overlapping and that may determine the cause of this issue:

```
VSCode: 
   Version: 1.52.0 (user setup)
   Commit: 940b5f4bb5fa47866a54529ed759d95d09ee80be
   Date: 2020-12-10T22:45:11.850Z
   Electron: 9.3.5
   Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
   Node.js: 12.14.1
   V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
   OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
Python:
   3.9.0
```

see discussion in comments for other details